# How to dynamically cast out decimal if zero or nonzeroes?

Tags: php, laravel

How to cast out data based on the following specification? I actually tried `number_format` but it turns out to be lengthy code (has a lot of multiple condition)?

- if data is `0.0027` it should remain `0.0027`
- if data is `0.0270` it should remain `0.027`
- if data is `0.027` it should remain `0.027`
- if data is `100.000` it should display just `100`
- if data is `100.1` it should display `100.1`

The only I could think of is creating a regex and create a custom cast in Laravel? Or at least do you have other solution for this one?

Comment: Are you working with strings? Have you tried to simply convert the data to floats?

Comment: @M.Eriksson nope its actually coming from a decimal column type.

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` and check the actual type of the values: https://3v4l.org/mEFg4. Cast them as floats should solve it though

Comment: @M.Eriksson thank you i just added a float cast in laravel and it is now working.